# Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter GUI program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm having trouble figuring out the logic behind why my code isn't working. I'm new to GUI programming and java as well, and I'm still a little rough on the format of creating a GUI program. In the code I'm trying to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class myGUIClass<FahrenheitButtonHandler> extends JFrame{

    private JLabel msgCelsius;
    private JLabel msgFahrenheit;
    private JButton btnCelsius;
    private JButton btnFahrenheit;
    private static JTextField fldCelsius;
    private static JTextField fldFahrenheit;
    Container contain;


    public myGUIClass(String myGUIWindow){
        super("myGui");
        contain = getContentPane();
        contain.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        msgCelsius = new JLabel("Degrees in Celsius");
        btnCelsius = new JButton("Convert From Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        fldCelsius = new JTextField(15);

        msgFahrenheit = new JLabel("Degrees in Fahrenheit  ");
        btnFahrenheit = new JButton("Convert From Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        fldFahrenheit = new JTextField(15);

        contain.add(msgCelsius);
        contain.add(fldCelsius);
        contain.add(btnCelsius);

        contain.add(msgFahrenheit);
        contain.add(fldFahrenheit);
        contain.add(btnFahrenheit);

        CelsiusButtonHandler btnHandlerCelsius = new CelsiusButtonHandler();
        btnCelsius.addActionListener(btnHandlerCelsius);

        FahrenheitButtonHandler btnHandlerFahrenheit = new FahrenheitButtonHandler();
        btnFahrenheit.addActionListener(btnHandlerFahrenheit);

        setSize(400,200);   
        setVisible(true);


    }//end method

    private class CelsiusButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        //@Override

        //implement the listener interface methods to process the events
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

            Integer celsius;
            Integer fahrenheit;

            try{
                if (ae.getSource() == btnCelsius){
                    celsius = Integer.parseInt(fldCelsius.getText());
                    fahrenheit = Math.round((9 /(float)5)) * (celsius + 32);
                    fldFahrenheit.setText(fahrenheit.toString());
                }//end if
            }//end try

            catch (Exception e){
                fldFahrenheit.setText("");
            }//end catch
    }//end inner class

        }//end class

    private class FahrenheitButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
            Integer fahrenheit1;
            Integer celsius1;

            try{
                if(a.getSource()== btnFahrenheit){
                    fahrenheit1 = Integer.parseInt(fldFahrenheit.getText());
                    celsius1 = Math.round((5 / (float)9)) * (fahrenheit1 - 32);
                    fldCelsius.setText(celsius1.toString());
                    }//end if
            }//end try

            catch (Exception e){
                fldCelsius.setText("");
            }//end catch

        }//end method
        }//end private class


    public static void main (String[] args){
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        myGUIClass guiClass = new myGUIClass(null);
        guiClass.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }//end main
    }//end outer class

       //theres a problem with the math in these lines:
       //am i not casting these correctly? whenever i input 50 i'm supposed to get 122 but i get 164.
       //fahrenheit = Math.round((9 /(float)5)) * (celsius + 32);
       //celsius1 = Math.round((5 / (float)9)) * (fahrenheit1 - 32);
```

Comment: And the problem is....?

Comment: When i run it and try to input a temperature in Fahrenheit it doesn't display anything in the Celsius's text field. Same problem the other way around

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it not convert? Does it not compile? Why does your class have a generic in the declaration, and why are you suppressing the raw types warning afterwards?

Comment: You example code is not compilable, let alone runnable...

Comment: You have an integer division problem and are assigning the wrong value to `fldCelsius`...

Comment: Sorry, but when all you say is "it doesn't work", without any example inputs and results, etc, you're gonna get downvoted and closed.

Comment: I changed the code so it will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the code issues that make the example uncompliable...

You have an integer division problem...

```
celsius = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
```

If `5/9` = `0` as the resulting value is converted to an integer.

Try using something more like...

```
celsius = Math.round((5 / (float)9)) * (fahrenheit - 32);
```

Now, personally, I would be using a `double` or `float` instead of an `int` and formatting the result but that's me.  You'll need to do the same thing `FahrenheitButtonHandler`

In your `FahrenheitButtonHandler` class, you are also applying the wrong value to the text field...

```
celsius1 = Integer.parseInt(fldFahrenheit.getText());
fahrenheit1 = celsius1*(9/5)+32;
fldCelsius.setText(celsius1.toString());
```

You applying the `celsius1` value, which is the value your extract from the `fldFahrenheit` field, not the calculated result, it should be

```
fldCelsius.setText(fahrenheit1.toString());
```

...but remember, there is still the interger division problem you need to correct for this...

Finally, you registered the wrong `ActionListener` to the `btnFahrenheit`

```
FahrenheitButtonHandler btnHandlerFahrenheit = new FahrenheitButtonHandler();
btnFahrenheit.addActionListener(btnHandlerCelsius); // <-- Wrong listener...
```

It should be...

```
FahrenheitButtonHandler btnHandlerFahrenheit = new FahrenheitButtonHandler();
btnFahrenheit.addActionListener(btnHandlerFahrenheit);
```